# Transform right skewed distribution to normal

Tags: skewness, histogram

My datasets histogram is the following:

[image]

It contains a lot of zeros, that is why the high bar around zero. How can I transform this to a normal distribution? My problem is that the high bar coming from the zeros will not vanish after applying the usually suggested log transformation, and neither the reciprocal transformation helps, as in that case the high bar will be at 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "It has a lot of zeroes" --- then you can't transform it to be approximately normal. e.g. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222167/appropriate-data-transformation/ and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124059/how-to-transform-continuous-data-with-extreme-bimodal-distribution/

Comment: Thanks Glen_b! You are so right. Now I see, that this is obvious. Does this mean, that using this feature in a linear model is not a good idea, as its distribution is far away from normal?

Comment: There's really no need for predictors (features) in a linear model to be normally distributed and trying to make them so may well ruin a previously linear relationship. (A number of answers and comments one site discuss this, too)